# Sending data to an Ember template

Tags: arrays, ember.js, ember-data

I have a question about sending data to an ember template. I have an array with the data :

```
var data = [ {
    "Coefficients": "Herkomst ouders: Een van de ouders Nederlands en de andere 
     niet Nederlands",
    "Categorie": "Herkomst",
    "Name": "Een van de ouders Nederlands en de andere niet Nederlands",
    "Gewicht": "-0,08943"
  },  {
    "Coefficients": "Type huishouden: Eenouderhuishouden",
    "Categorie": "Type huishouden",
    "Name": "Eenouderhuishouden",
    "Gewicht": "0,49608"
  }]
```

I have a lot more data in it with diffrent category's (Categorie). In the same file I have this code :

```
var data_prepped = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  var new_cat = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < data_prepped.length; j++) {
    if (data_prepped[j].Categorie === data[i].Categorie) {
      new_cat = false;
    }
  }

  if (new_cat) {
    data_prepped.push({
      'Categorie': data[i].Categorie,
      'Antwoorden': []
    });
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < data_prepped.length; j++) {
    if (data_prepped[j].Categorie === data[i].Categorie) {
      data_prepped[j].Antwoorden.push({
        'Coefficients': data[i].Coefficients,
        'Name': data[i].Name,
        'Gewicht': data[i].Gewicht,
      });
    }
  }
}

export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return data_prepped;
    }
});
```

In my template file from ember I run this code :

```
<section class="category">
                    <h1>Algemeen</h1>
                {{#each data_prepped as |data|}}
                        <h5>{{data.Categorie}}</h5>
                    <select class="" name="">
                        {{#each data.Antwoorden as |antwoord|}}                 
                            <option data-weight="{{antwoord.Gewicht}}" name="{{antwoord.Name}}">
                                {{antwoord.Name}}
                            </option>
                        {{/each}}
                    </select>
                {{/each}}
            </section>
```

This is working for me but it give me back all the data from the array. But I only want just a part of the data for example this category : **"Categorie": "Type huishouden"**. How can I fix this?

Comment: What, specifically, are you wanting to do?
Like, render different data based on different entries in the array?
If so, what are the criteria for deciding which entry to render which set of data?
Sorry if I'm confused

Comment: I want to show the data in a select field that is in a section for example : 
Section A + Category A 
Section B + Catergory B
Section C + Category C
All the data is one array so at the moment I get this :
Section A + All the data from the array but in stead of that i want it like above.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the data you don't want to show from `data_prepped`. Maybe like this:

export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return data_prepped.filter(d => d.Categorie === 'Type huishouden');
    }
});

Next you probably want this dynamic, so you add a dynamic param to your route. So in your router you could do this:

```
this.route('category', { path: '/category/:cat' });
```

Then you can do this in your `model()` hook:

```
model({ cat }) {
    return data_prepped.filter(d => d.Categorie === cat);
}
```

And next you can use URLs like `/category/Type%20huishouden` to access a specific category. (`%20` escapes the space)

---

However for a real app you probably don't want your data in your source code. And then the question is where does your data come from, how do you get it, and how can you get only the data for a specific category. But thats basically your backend API and not ember related.